# Count the number of dates that a criteria is met

Tags: excel, frequency

I have a worksheet with over 30,000 entries in it of work logs submitted by a team of 15 individuals. I've broken this down using a range of countif/sumif/sumproduct formulas to try and summarise the data but am struggling to get one to work for counting the number of days a worklog was submitted by each member of staff over the period(baring in mind that each date the members of the team are working they are submitting multiple worklogs for various types of work).

I understand this is easily done with a pivot table but am trying to avoid using them for this as it will need to be presented/used by other members of staff who are not regular excel users. I would like to make this as simple for them as possible while being able to use the number of days they were at work to calculate averages etc.

I suspect I'm missing something easy here but any advice anyone can offer would be really appreciated.

The dates are in D41:D32038 and names of the workers that submit them in F41:F32308. Thank you.

Comment: this link will probably help: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4091-excel-count-unique-values-based-on-multiple-criteria.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Pivots are the way to go, but try this array-formula:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(F41:F32308="name of worker",MATCH(INT(D41:D32038),INT(D41:D32038),0)),ROW(D41:D32038)-ROW(D41)+1)>0))
```

Change name of  worker' to the name you're looking for
The result should be the count of (unique) days for a worker, Close Formula with CSE

Comment: Hi EvR, thanks so much for your reply. That formula is returning the total number of entries made by the worker rather than just the count of the unique days they've made an entry on. Just to double check all I have changed is the name of the worker and I've made sure the dates are in date format. Any ideas?  Fully agree about pivots but I'm trying to save them filtering and prepopulate as much as possible for them.

Comment: This dates in Column D, are these only dates? Or do they have a time in it which isn't shown by format? Formula above counts unique...I'll change above formula whenthis is the case

Comment: It was in date/time, sorry I should have picked this up before replying. Have written in to adjust for this and works perfectly now. Thank you again for your help!